# legal to use screenshots/videos from games

Tags: united-states, copyright, germany

I'd like to use screenshots from video games like Minecraft or Contraption Maker in presentations.  Is this legal?

My reasoning pro:

- I've seen screenshots from other software all over the place and can't imagine an MS Word tutorial with screenshots (including logos or clippy) to be illegal.
- In the case of these specific games, what is seen is to a large extend the result of my own creativity.
- Contraption Maker has a function to export videos and upload them to YouTube.  There is nothing in the documentation of that feature that says that's only allowed in specific circumstances or the videos are licensed only for some purposes.

My reasoning against:

- The amount of creativity that goes into the scene that is screen shot varies a lot from game to game.  I wouldn't expect a screenshot from an in-game video to be free to use.  It seems unlikely that there's a blanket rule that screenshots from software are the property of the one making the screenshot.
- Even in Minecraft and Contraption Maker, the components of each scene were drawn by artists and those drawings are the property of the owners of Contraption Maker.

Edit:
I just found [this](https://account.mojang.com/terms): in the case of Minecraft, it seems to be legal, because it is explicitly allowed to "write and publish works inspired by Minecraft".  The question about the general situation remains. Also, I haven't been able to find anything about Contraption Maker.

Edited II:
I'm interested in answers regarding German law, but also US-American.

Comment: Did you take the screenshots yourself?

Comment: @Studoku : Not yet, but I would.

Comment: @RockApe : Thank you, yes, that's the question I linked to in my last comment.